# Finding the fourth moment about the mean of a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Problem:
Find the fourth moment about the mean of a uniform distribution.

Answer:
Let $u_4$ be the moment we seek. The lower and upper bounds of this distribution are $a$ and $b$. The density function for the
uniform distribution is:
$$ f(x) = \dfrac{1}{b-a} \text{.}$$
This gives us a mean of $(a+b)/2$.
\begin{align*}
u_4 &= E\left( \left( x - u\right) ^4  \right)
 = E\left( \left( x^2 - 2ux + u^2 \right) ^2 \right) \\
u_4 &= E\Big(
 x^2 \left( x^2 - 2ux + u^2 \right)
 - 2ux \left( x^2 - 2ux + u^2 \right)
 + u^2 \left( x^2 - 2ux + u^2 \right) \Big) \\
u_4 &= E\Big(
  x^4 - 2ux^3 + u^2 x^2 
 -2ux^3 + 4u^2x^2 - 2u^3x + u^2 \left( x^2 - 2ux + u^2 \right) \Big) \\
%
u_4 &= E\Big(
 x^4 - 2ux^3 + 5u^2 x^2 
 - 2ux^3 - 2u^3x + u^2 \left( x^2 - 2ux + u^2 \right) \Big) \\
%
u_4 &= E\Big( x^4 - 2ux^3 + 5u^2 x^2 
 - 2ux^3 - 2u^3x + u^2 x^2  - 2u^3x + u^4 \Big) \\
%
u_4 &= E\Big( x^4  - 4ux^3 + 6u^2 x^2 - 4u^3x  + u^4 \Big) \\
u_4 &= E( x^4 )  - 4uE(x^3) + 6u^2E(x^2) - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
E( x^4 ) &= \int_a^b \dfrac{x^4}{b-a} \,\, dx
 = \dfrac{x^5}{5(b-a)} \Big|_{a}^{b} \\
E( x^4 ) &= \dfrac{ b^5 } { 5(b-a) } - \dfrac{ a^5 } { 5(b-a) }
 = \dfrac{ b^5 - a^5 } { 5(b-a) } \\
E( x^4 ) &= \dfrac{ (b-a)(b^4 + b^3a + b^2a^2 + ba^3 + a^4) } { 5(b-a) }  \\
%
E( x^4 ) &= \dfrac{ b^4 + b^3a + b^2a^2 + ba^3 + a^4 } { 5 } \\
%
E( x^3 ) &= \int_a^b \dfrac{x^3}{b-a} \,\, dx
 = \dfrac{ x^4 }{4(b-a)} \Big|_{a}^{b} \\
E( x^3 ) &= \dfrac{ b^4 }{4(b-a)} - \dfrac{ a^4 }{4(b-a)}
 = \dfrac{ b^4 - a^4}{4(b-a)} \\
E( x^3 ) &= \dfrac{ (b - a)( b+a )(b^2+a^2)}{4(b-a)} \\
E( x^3 ) &=  \dfrac{ ( b+a )(b^2+a^2)}{4} \\
%
E( x^2 ) &= \int_a^b \dfrac{x^2}{b-a} \,\, dx
 = \dfrac{ x^3 } { 3(b-a) } \Big|_{a}^{b} \\
E( x^2 ) &= \dfrac{ b^3 } { 3(b-a) } - \dfrac{ a^3 } { 3(b-a) }
 = \dfrac{ b^3 - a^3 } { 3(b-a) } \\
E( x^2 ) &= \dfrac{ (b-a)(b^2 + ab + a^2)} { 3(b-a) } \\
E( x^2 ) &= \dfrac{ b^2 + ab + a^2} { 3 } \\
u_4 &=
 \dfrac{ b^4 + b^3a + b^2a^2 + ba^3 + a^4 } { 5 } 
  - 4u\left(  \dfrac{ ( b+a )(b^2+a^2)}{4}\right) 
 + 6u^2E(x^2) - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
%
u_4 &=
 \dfrac{ b^4 + b^3a + b^2a^2 + ba^3 + a^4 } { 5 } 
 - \left( \dfrac{b+a}{2} \right) \left(  ( b+a )(b^2+a^2)\right) \\ 
 +& 6 \left( \left( \dfrac{b+a}{2}\right) ^2 \right) E(x^2)
 - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
u_4 &=
 \dfrac{ b^4 + b^3a + b^2a^2 + ba^3 + a^4 } { 5 } 
 - \left( \dfrac{b+a}{2} \right) \left(  ( b+a )(b^2+a^2)\right) \\ 
 +& \left( \dfrac{6}{4} \right)
  \left( \left( (b+a)\right) ^2 \right)
   \left(  \dfrac{ b^2 + ab + a^2} { 3 } \right) 
  - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
u_4 &=
 \dfrac{ b^4 + b^3a + b^2a^2 + ba^3 + a^4 } { 5 } 
 - \left( \dfrac{ (b+a)^2(b^2+a^2) }{2}\right) \\ 
 +& \left( \dfrac{6}{4} \right)
   \left( \left( (b+a)\right) ^2 \right)
   \left(  \dfrac{ b^2 + ab + a^2} { 3 } \right) 
 - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
u_4 &= \dfrac{ 2b^4 + 2b^3a + 2b^2a^2 + 2ba^3 + 2a^4 } { 10 } 
 - \left( \dfrac{ (b^2+2ba+a^2)(b^2+a^2) }{2}\right) \\ 
 +& \left( \dfrac{6}{4} \right)
 \left( \left( (b+a)\right) ^2 \right)
 \left(  \dfrac{ b^2 + ab + a^2} { 3 } \right) 
 - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
%
u_4 &= \dfrac{ 2b^4 + 2b^3a + 2b^2a^2 + 2ba^3 + 2a^4 } { 10 } 
 - \left( \dfrac{ b^4 + 2b^3a + b^2a^2 + b^2a^2 + 2ba^3 + a^4 }{2}\right) \\ 
 +& \left( \dfrac{6}{4} \right)
 \left( \left( (b+a)\right) ^2 \right)
 \left(  \dfrac{ b^2 + ab + a^2} { 3 } \right) 
 - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
%
u_4 &= \dfrac{ 2b^4 + 2b^3a + 2b^2a^2 + 2ba^3 + 2a^4 } { 10 } 
- \left( \dfrac{ 10b^4 + 20b^3a + 20b^2a^2 + 20ba^3 + 10a^4 }{10}\right) \\ 
+& \left( \dfrac{6}{4} \right)
\left( (b+a)\right) ^2
\left(  \dfrac{ b^2 + ab + a^2} { 3 } \right) 
- 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
%
u_4 &= \dfrac{ -8b^4 - 18b^3a - 18b^2a^2 - 18ba^3 - 8a^4 } { 10 } \\
+& \left( \dfrac{6}{4} \right)
\left( (b+a)\right) ^2 
\left(  \dfrac{ b^2 + ab + a^2} { 3 } \right) 
- 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
%
u_4 &= \dfrac{ -8b^4 - 18b^3a - 18b^2a^2 - 18ba^3 - 8a^4 } { 10 }
 + \left( \dfrac{2}{4} \right)\left( (b+a)\right)^2
  \left( b^2 + ab + a^2 \right) 
 - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
%
u_4 &= \dfrac{ -8b^4 - 18b^3a - 18b^2a^2 - 18ba^3 - 8a^4 } { 10 }
 + \left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right)\left( b^2 + 2ba + a^2\right)
 \left( b^2 + ab + a^2 \right) 
 - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
%
u_4 &= \dfrac{ -8b^4 - 18b^3a - 18b^2a^2 - 18ba^3 - 8a^4 } { 10 }
 + \dfrac{b^4 + 3b^3a + 4b^2a^2 + 3ba^3 + a^4 }{2}
 - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
%
u_4 &= \dfrac{ -8b^4 - 18b^3a - 18b^2a^2 - 18ba^3 - 8a^4 } { 10 }
 + \dfrac{5b^4 + 15b^3a + 20b^2a^2 + 15ba^3 + 5a^4 }{10}
 - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
%
u_4 &=
 \dfrac{ -3b^4 - 18b^3a - 18b^2a^2 - 18ba^3 - 8a^4 + 15b^3a
   + 20b^2a^2 + 15ba^3 + 5a^4 } { 10 }
 - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
%
u_4 &=
 \dfrac{ -3b^4 - 3b^3a - 2b^2a^2 - 3ba^3 - 3a^4 } { 10 }
 - 4u^3 E(x)  + u^4 \\
%
u_4 &=
 \dfrac{ -3b^4 - 3b^3a - 2b^2a^2 - 3ba^3 - 3a^4 } { 10 } - 3u^4 \\
%
u_4 &=
 \dfrac{ -3b^4 - 3b^3a - 2b^2a^2 - 3ba^3 - 3a^4 } { 10 }
 - \dfrac{3(b+a)^4}{16} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
u_4 &=
\dfrac{ 8(-3b^4 - 3b^3a - 2b^2a^2 - 3ba^3 - 3a^4) } { 80 }
 - \dfrac{15(b+a)^4}{80} \\
%
u_4 &=
 \dfrac{ -24b^4 - 24b^3a - 16b^2a^2 - 24ba^3 - 24a^4 } { 80 }
 - \dfrac{15(b^4 + 4b^3a + 6b^2a^2 + 4ba^3 + a^4)}{80} \\
%
u_4 &=
 \dfrac{ -39b^4 - 84b^3a - 106b^2a^2 - 84ba^3 - 39a^4 } { 80 }
\end{align*}
However, the book gets:
$$ \dfrac{ (b-a)^4 }{ 80 } $$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Using the same symbol to refer both to the random variable and the argument to its pdf or its cdf has problems. Often one uses capital $X$ for the random variable and lower-case $x$ for the argument to the pdf or the cdf.

Comment: You have made an arithmetic error.  Perhaps you turned $ \left( \frac{ b^4 + 2b^3a + b^2a^2 + b^2a^2 + 2ba^3 + a^4 }{2}\right)$ into $\left( \frac{ 10b^4 + 20b^3a + 20b^2a^2 + 20ba^3 + 10a^4 }{10}\right)$ instead of $\left( \frac{ 5b^4 + 10b^3a + 10b^2a^2 + 10ba^3 + 5a^4 }{10}\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you do it that way?

If $X \sim U[a,b]$ then let $Y= X-\bar X= X-\frac{a+b}{2}\sim U\left[-\frac{b-a}{2},\frac{b-a}{2}\right]$  with density $\frac1{b-a}$ on that interval.

The fourth moment about the mean of $X$ is then the fourth moment about $0$  of $Y$: $$\mathbb E\left[Y^4\right]=\int\limits_{-(b-a)/2}^{(b-a)/2} \frac{y^4}{(b-a)}\, dy = \left.\frac{y^5}{5(b-a)}\right|_{-(b-a)/2}^{(b-a)/2} = \frac{(b-a)^4}{80}$$